# NumPy matrix with two entries in the same cell is not working

Tags: python, numpy

I am working in Python and I am not able to find the correct solution for this problem. I should not use a loop like 'for' or 'while' in these case. Here is a simplified example of what I need to solve:

```
import numpy as np

grid_data = np.zeros([5, 5])

data = np.array([[10.0, 10.5, 2.0, -9999.0], [1.0, 0.1, -9999.0, 0.05]])
idx_lat = np.array([[2, 2, 0, 3], [3, 3, 2, 1]], dtype=int)
idx_lon = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 0]], dtype=int)
idx_data = np.where(data > 0)

grid_data[idx_lat[idx_data], idx_lon[idx_data]] += data[idx_data]
```

The grid_data should give me the following output:

```
In [26]: grid_data
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  2.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.05,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [20.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.1 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

But Python is returning me the following grid_data:

```
In [26]: grid_data
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  2.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.05,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [10.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.1 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

Do you know how to fix it?

I tried the code showed before, but it is not giving me what I expected.

Comment: `np.add.at` can do `+=` with duplicate indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already hinted by @hpaulj, you can use [np.add.at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), which

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once.

Which is exactly what you need here:

```py
import numpy as np

grid_data = np.zeros([5, 5])
data = np.array([[10.0, 10.5, 2.0, -9999.0], [1.0, 0.1, -9999.0, 0.05]])
idx_lat = np.array([[2, 2, 0, 3], [3, 3, 2, 1]], dtype=int)
idx_lon = np.array([[0, 0, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 0]], dtype=int)

idx_data = np.where(data > 0)

np.add.at(grid_data, (idx_lat[idx_data], idx_lon[idx_data]), data[idx_data])

print(grid_data)
```

output is

```py
[[ 0.    0.    0.    2.    0.  ]
 [ 0.05  0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [20.5   0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    1.    0.1 ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]]
```